# Material visibility when rotating viewport

Tags: 3d, maya, modeling

I set the material for [Unity-chan!](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/unity-chan-model-18705)

When I set the eye material and rotate the viewport, the eye material disappears. How to make it always visible?

[image]

I can change viewport 2.0 option > transparent algorithm to “depth peeling”, it will fix material disappear in Maya, but when I export my Maya project to FBX and use FBX in unity editor, this bug still exist.

Comment: Isn't it just a preview issue? Does the issue still persists in the final render? (What's the final use of this file?)

Answer (score 0):

I find a tmp solution:

- I reset all character head object (click “head” group in outliner), in viewport, assign material with lambert1 (Maya default material)
- and first assign eye material, this bug doesn't occur
- and set material for all head objects, one by one, when assign one material, rotate viewport to see whether this bug reproduce
- finally, I find when I set “eyebase” material, this bug occurs

So I changed eyebase material, this bug is fixed.

I still wanna know why set other object material will cause eye material to disappear.

Comment: Try to delete object history. I don't recall where is that option, somewhere in `Edit - Delete by Type` or something like that.

Comment: @SylwesterPilarz Shaders are not in history tree so it will not help.